# Is the any way to install cmake for Android studio on a 32bit system to allow C++ support?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake

Latest version of AS and windows 7 32bit.

After some research it seems as though cmake for AS only runs on 64bit systems, if correct I assume there is no way I can just download cmake for 32bit and place it in the appropriate location in the Android SDK, or is there any other work around, I am pretty sure I will need to install windows 64bit, but thought I'd ask.

This is so I can have C++/NDK support in AS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, AS only supports 64 bit OS's to build c and c++ with cmake

Comment: This does not answer the question